# Get owner of file on disk

Tags: excel, vba

Below is my current macro, which is working great, but I would like to add in Cells(r, 10) the owner of the file. How can such a thing be accomplished? I can't find the command to use like File.Owner or something.

```
Sub DoFolder(Folder)
If Ans = vbNo Then GoTo NoSub                                           'Switching according to ans.
Dim SubFolder
For Each SubFolder In Folder.SubFolders
    DoFolder SubFolder
Next
NoSub:
Dim File
For Each File In Folder.Files
    FName = File.Name
    If InStrRev(FName, ".") = 0 Then GoTo NextFile                      'If "." not found then go to next file
    Cells(r, 1) = Left(FName, InStrRev(FName, ".") - 1)                 'File Name
    ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Cells(r, 2), _
                               Address:=File.Path, _
                               TextToDisplay:=File.Path                 'Hyperlinking Path
    Cells(r, 3) = File.DateLastModified                                 'Date Last Modified
    Cells(r, 4) = Round(File.Size / 1024, 3)                            'in KBs Rounded to 3 Decimal places
    Cells(r, 5) = Right(FName, Len(FName) - InStrRev(FName, ".") + 1)   'File Extension
    r = r + 1
NextFile:
Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access the file's security properties (one of which is the Owner), through the Security Utility object.

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()
    Dim fName As String
    Dim fDir As String
    fName = "test.txt"
    fDir = "C:\Temp\"
    Debug.Print "The owner is " & GetFileOwner(fDir, fName)
End Sub

Function GetFileOwner(fileDir As String, fileName As String) As String
    Dim securityUtility As Object
    Dim securityDescriptor As Object
    Set securityUtility = CreateObject("ADsSecurityUtility")
    Set securityDescriptor = securityUtility.GetSecurityDescriptor(fileDir & fileName, 1, 1)
    GetFileOwner = securityDescriptor.owner
End Function
```

Comment: I would say to copy the function in answer to your modeule and then add the line `Cells(r, 10) = GetFileOwner(Folder.FolderPath, FName)` just before `r = r + 1`. I did not try to run your code because most of your variables are not defined (put `Option Explicit` at the top of your module), and it looks recursive.